# How to call onBackPressed() method from RecyclerView adapter on click of Android back button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview, onbackpressed

I'm Launching an Alert Dialog after clicking on a row item in RecyclerView adapter. I want to close the alert dialog on click of back button. I've an overridden method in activity, I'm a little confused about how to call this from adapter.

Comment: Pass reference of activity in adapter via constructor. And you can call on activity.onBackpressed() from Adapter.

Comment: you can `cast` your `context` into activity and call `onBackpressed()` on that..

Comment: ((Activity) mContext).onBackPressed(); this if fine. but my question is when to call this method

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed()` is an activity method. You need to pass your activity instance to the adapter's constructor and then you can call onBackPressed from that activity instance

Your constructor should be as follows:

> `Activity activity
>       Myadapter(Activity activity){
>           this.activity = activity;
>       }
>       // Now call this method from             anywhere activity.onBackPressed()`